# Passing state data to another react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'm trying to pass array of data to another component, the component is FeedbackList.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import FeedbackItem from "./FeedbackItem";

function FeedbackList({ feedback }) {
  if (!feedback || feedback.length === 0) {
    return <p>No Feedback</p>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="feedback-list">
      {feedback.map((item) => (
          <FeedbackItem key={item.id} item={item.item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default FeedbackList
```

the reason why I use FeedbackItem to map each data above is because I want to use styles from FeedbackItem component, this is the FeedbackItem

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function FeedbackItem() {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(7);
  const [text, setText] = useState('Feedback Item')

  // const handleClick = () => {
  //     setRating(10)
  // }

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="num-display">{rating}</div>
      <div className="text-display">{text}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FeedbackItem;
```

this is FeedbackData that contain the array of data that i want to show in FeedbackList

```
const FeedbackData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    rating: 5,
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sed iaculis justo. Aliquam accumsan tempus lobortis. Praesent at nulla eleifend urna ultricies placerat. Vivamus efficitur, sem in cursus iaculis, massa nibh fringilla urna, a fringilla nisi elit vel ligula. Aenean viverra justo auctor mi lacinia dapibus. Quisque vel sem faucibus odio aliquam pretium et consequat magna. Sed felis libero, porttitor non viverra non, aliquet eget lectus. Quisque dictum tellus in mi lacinia molestie. In ullamcorper urna risus, eu sollicitudin diam tempor in.",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    rating: 15,
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sed iaculis justo. Aliquam accumsan tempus lobortis. Praesent at nulla eleifend urna ultricies placerat. Vivamus efficitur, sem in cursus iaculis, massa nibh fringilla urna, a fringilla nisi elit vel ligula. Aenean viverra justo auctor mi lacinia dapibus. Quisque vel sem faucibus odio aliquam pretium et consequat magna. Sed felis libero, porttitor non viverra non, aliquet eget lectus. Quisque dictum tellus in mi lacinia molestie. In ullamcorper urna risus, eu sollicitudin diam tempor in.",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    rating: 7,
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sed iaculis justo. Aliquam accumsan tempus lobortis. Praesent at nulla eleifend urna ultricies placerat. Vivamus efficitur, sem in cursus iaculis, massa nibh fringilla urna, a fringilla nisi elit vel ligula. Aenean viverra justo auctor mi lacinia dapibus. Quisque vel sem faucibus odio aliquam pretium et consequat magna. Sed felis libero, porttitor non viverra non, aliquet eget lectus. Quisque dictum tellus in mi lacinia molestie. In ullamcorper urna risus, eu sollicitudin diam tempor in.",
  },
]

export default FeedbackData
```

and this is my App.js, when I use React Devtools extension to view the app hooks state, the FeedbackData shows up but it won't display in the FeedbackItem, it says "No Feedback" when in fact there are Feedback data

```
import Header from "./components/Header";
import FeedbackList from "./components/FeedbackList";
import {useState} from 'react'
import FeedbackData from "./data/FeedbackData";
import FeedbackItem from "./components/FeedbackItem";

function App() {
  const [data, setdata] = useState(FeedbackData)


  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="container">
        <FeedbackList />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Comment: `<FeedbackList />` You're not passing any props into feedback list. Did you mean `<FeedbackList feedback={data} />`?

Comment: it shows three cards with rating 7 and string of "Feedback Item" instead, it seems it shows up the useState in my FeedbackItem component

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
  const [data, setdata] = useState(FeedbackData)


  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="container">
        <FeedbackList data={FeedbackData}/>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


export default App;


function FeedbackList({ feedback }) {
  if (!feedback || feedback.length === 0) {
    return <p>No Feedback</p>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="feedback-list">
      {feedback.map((item) => (
          <FeedbackItem key={item.id} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default FeedbackList;

function FeedbackItem = (props) => {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(7);
  const [text, setText] = useState('Feedback Item');

  const {item} = props;

  // const handleClick = () => {
  //     setRating(10)
  // }

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="num-display">{item.rating}</div>
      <div className="text-display">{item.text}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FeedbackItem;
```

Comment: using React Devtools, the props is now showing up in the FeedbackList (previously the props was empty), but i have no idea why it still show up as No Feedback https://snipboard.io/S6GaWu.jpg